# Am I using nHibernate's ISession properly here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, session

I'm starting out with nHibernate and want to do it right from day one so here is how I am using the ISession. (Web per request)

This is my helper:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Cfg.MappingSchema;
using NHibernate.Context;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;
using NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

namespace Gigastence.nHibernate.Web
{
    public static class Helper
    {
        #region Public Enums

        public enum DatabaseType
        {
            MSSQL2005,
            MSSQL2008,
            MySQL,
            MySQL5
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Members

        private static HbmMapping _hbmMapping;
        private static Type[] _mappingTypes;
        private static Configuration _nHibernateConfiguration;

        #endregion

        #region Public Properties

        public static bool GenerateStatistics { get; set; }
        public static string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        public static ISession GetCurrentSession
        {
            get
            {
                //  Store the current ISession
                ISession tempSession = GetSessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

                //  Return the current Session in for the relevant Context
                return tempSession.IsOpen ? tempSession : OpenSession();
            }
        }

        public static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory { get; private set; }
        public static DatabaseType WorkingDatabaseType { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        private static void CompileSessionFactory()
        {
            //  ToDo: See if we can speed up this process by creating a static file to reference
            //
            //  Build the nHibernate Configuration and store it
            _nHibernateConfiguration = ConfigureNHibernate();

            //  Deserialize and Add the supplied Mappings to the nHibernate Configuration
            _nHibernateConfiguration.AddDeserializedMapping(_hbmMapping, null);

            //  ToDo: Figure out what this does!
            //
            SchemaMetadataUpdater.QuoteTableAndColumns(_nHibernateConfiguration);

            //  Create the Session Factory and store it
            GetSessionFactory = _nHibernateConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory();
        }

        private static Configuration ConfigureNHibernate()
        {
            //  Create a new nHibernate configuration
            var configure = new Configuration();

            //      ToDo: Allow for setting name of SessionFactory
            //
            //  Name the Session Factory
            configure.SessionFactoryName("Default");

            //  Wire up Session Factory Database component based on working database type
            switch (WorkingDatabaseType)
            {
                case DatabaseType.MySQL5:

                    //  !!! Is a MySQL 5 Database
                    configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                    {
                        db.Dialect<MySQL5Dialect>();
                        db.Driver<MySqlDataDriver>();
                        db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                        db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                        db.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                        db.Timeout = 10;
                    });
                    break;
            }

            //  Generate Statistics, if required
            if (GenerateStatistics) configure.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

            //  ToDo: Add modifier based on required Session Context
            //
            configure.CurrentSessionContext<ManagedWebSessionContext>();

            //  Return the Configuration
            return configure;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public static void AddMapping(Type mappingType)
        {
            //  Determine if array is already available
            if (_mappingTypes == null)
            {
                //  Create a new array with one element
                _mappingTypes = new Type[1];
            }

            //  Copy existing array into a new array with one more element
            Array.Resize(ref _mappingTypes, _mappingTypes.Length + 1);

            //  Add the Mapping Type
            Array.Copy(new object[] { mappingType }, 0, _mappingTypes, _mappingTypes.Length - 1, 1);
        }

        public static void AddMappings(Type[] mappingTypes)
        {
            //  Iterate through passed types
            foreach(Type passedType in mappingTypes)
            {
                //  Add each typre
                AddMapping(passedType);
            }
        }

        public static void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            //  Add the ISession object to the current request's Context for use throughout the request
            ManagedWebSessionContext.Bind(HttpContext.Current, OpenSession());
        }

        public static void Application_End()
        {
            //  Dispose of the Session Factory
            GetSessionFactory.Dispose();
        }

        public static void Application_EndRequest()
        {
            //  Unbind the Session from the request's context and place in the ISession holder
            ISession session = ManagedWebSessionContext.Unbind(HttpContext.Current, GetSessionFactory);

            //  Flush and Close the Session if it is still open
            if (session == null || !session.IsOpen) return;

            //  Proceed
            session.Flush();
            session.Close();
            session.Dispose();
        }

        public static void Application_Error()
        {
            //  Rollback transaction if there is one
            RollbackTransaction();
        }

        public static void BuildDatabase()
        {
            //  ToDo: Tidy Up and extend
            new SchemaExport(_nHibernateConfiguration).Execute(false, true, false);
        }

        public static void BuildSessionFactory(bool forceRebuild)
        {
            //  Determine if this is a forced rebuild
            if (forceRebuild)
            {
                //  !!! Forced rebuild

                //  Compile Session Factory
                CompileSessionFactory();
            }
            else
            {
                //  !!! Not a forced rebuild

                //  Reference the current Session Factory if available
                ISessionFactory sessionFactory = GetSessionFactory;

                //  Determine if Session Factory is built already
                if (sessionFactory == null)
                {
                    //  Compile Session Factory
                    CompileSessionFactory();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void CompileMappings(Type baseEntityToIgnore)
        {
            //  Using the built-in auto-mapper
            var mapper = new ModelMapper();

            //  Add prefetched Types to Mapper
            mapper.AddMappings(_mappingTypes);

            //  Compile the retrieved Types into the required Mapping
            _hbmMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
        }

        public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            return GetSessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        public static void RollbackTransaction()
        {
            //  Get the current ISession from the request's context and place in the ISession holder
            ISession session = GetCurrentSession;

            //  Determine if the ISession exists
            if (session == null) return;

            //  It does, rollback current transaction if there is one
            if (session.Transaction.IsActive && !session.Transaction.WasRolledBack)
            {
                //  There was a transaction, rollback
                session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

This is how I am using it:

```
using (ISession session = Helper.GetCurrentSession)
{
    using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //  Add data to the NHibernateSchemaVersions table
        var table = new NHibernateSchemaVersions { Component = "Web.Provider.Membership", Version = 1 };
        session.Save(table);

        transaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

So far I get this is what I should be doing, wrapping the work in a transaction.

I'm finding though, because of the USING statement on the ISession object, that the session is closed at the end of each call; this is why I added the logic to check if it was still open on the Helper.GetCurrentSession call.

Am I doing this right? I thought the session is meant to stay alive until the end of the request and it determines when it goes to the database.

Should I be simply fetching the session and using it as opposed to a USING statement:

```
ISession session = Helper.GetCurrentSession;

using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    //  Add data to the NHibernateSchemaVersions table
    var table = new NHibernateSchemaVersions { Component = "Web.Provider.Membership", Version = 1 };
    session.Save(table);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

If this is the case, will I run into issues elsewhere?

Thanks for your time and help.

Note: I did look for the answer but I couldn't relate my question to anything. Please do point me to a link if I have missed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue. I now explicitly `Dispose()` of the session at the end of the request--problem solved.

And since my library is also used in non web applications, my helper class and my repositories provide two entry points--one for "persistent" sessions (explicitly closed) and the other designed for per-trip sessions (implicitly closed with `using` statements).

Another very good use for "persistent" sessions is if you're using lazy loading on a relationship mapping. If you auto-close the session when you retrieve the "parent" object (by way of a `using` statement), and then you attempt to retrieve the lazy-load property, you will generate an exception because the session it will try to use has been closed.

**UPDATE**

As requested, here's my current helper class--mine's quite basic. All of my configuration is in an XML file. For my MVC web app, I'm closing the session in Global.asx in a listener for EndRequest by calling `NHibernateHelper.GetPersistentSession().Dispose()`.

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                var configuration = new NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateHelper).Assembly);
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    private static ISession _persistentSession = null;
    public static ISession GetPersistentSession()
    {
        if (_persistentSession == null)
        {
            _persistentSession = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }

        return _persistentSession;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question. While I would be more interested in the helper you have, my question relates to the Session closing before next use in the 'same' request, is this meant to happen? Does the session close when you commit the transaction?

Comment: No, the session doesn't close on commit. It closes when you explicitly close or dispose of the session. You can have one session with many transactions.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Does the USING statement close the session? Maybe that is where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yes, it does. A `using` statement basically wraps the contained code in a `try . . . finally` and in the `finally` block, it calls the `Dispose()` method of the item specified in the `using` statement, which in this case is your session. Basically, if you want to have a session open for the duration of an HTTP request (which is what I'm assuming you mean), you must either forego the `using` statement (and `Dispose` explicitly) or find a way to wrap the whole request in a `using` block (not recommmended).

Comment: Thanks, you confirmed my thoughts. I won;t use the using block anymore for the Session unless I have to; my Helper's Application_EndRequest Disposes the session for me. On another note, and being cheeky, do you think you would be able to provide me with a sample of your helper? I learn by example, and quite simply, there are that many examples out there I don't know which is what as is the right way. It's ok if you don;t want to supply it; completely understandable.

Comment: I don't mind sharing it, but it's identical to the NHibernateHelper in the "Your First NHibernate Application" tutorial, with the addition of an accessor for the persistent session and a static member to reference it.